# Meteor mobile-config.js push notification entitlement

Tags: meteor, push-notification

When submitting my app to the app store, I get this warning:

**Missing Push Notification Entitlement** - Your app appears to include API used to register with the Apple Push Notification service, but the app signature's entitlements do not include the "aps-environment" entitlement. If your app uses the Apple Push Notification service, make sure your App ID is enabled for Push Notification in the Provisioning Portal, and resubmit after signing your app with a Distribution provisioning profile that includes the "aps-environment" entitlement. See "Provisioning and Development" in the Local and Push Notification Programming Guide for more information. If your app does not use the Apple Push Notification service, no action is required. You may remove the API from future submissions to stop this warning. If you use a third-party framework, you may need to contact the developer for information on removing the API.

I am aware that the push notification entitlement can be set in the mobile-config.js file, but i can't find out what I need to add to that file so that config.xml gets built with the push notification entitlement.

What do I add to my mobile-config.js file?

Comment: i have exactly the same issue, any news?